# How to use memset function in two dimensional array for initialization of members in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I want to know how I can use the `memset()` function in a `two dimensional array` in C.

I don't want to face any garbage problems in that array. How do I initialize this array?

Could someone explain me how to achieve it?

Comment: The answer depends on whether the array is defined using stack memory or heap memory.

Comment: Whether on the stack or heap, using memset, as the Op requested, is no different.

Comment: Of course, using memset is not always the best way to go.  One solution - if malloc() is being used, try calloc() instead.

Comment: If you need to use memset and want help determining the size of the array, please post some code which shows how the array is being allocated.

Comment: This is my initialization code of define two dimensional array and i have to create two dimensional dynamic array, for this reason, i declare it in this way.  int **matrix;
 int **back;

Answer (score 32):

If your 2D array has static storage duration, then it is default-initialized to zero, i.e., all members of the array are set to zero.

If the 2D array has automatic storage duration, then you can use an array initializer list to set all members to zero.

```
int arr[10][20] = {0};  // easier way
// this does the same
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
```

If you allocate your array dynamically, then you can use `memset` to set all bytes to zero.

```
int *arr = malloc((10*20) * (sizeof *arr));
// check arr for NULL

// arr --> pointer to the buffer to be set to 0
// 0 --> value the bytes should be set to
// (10*20*) * (sizeof *arr) --> number of bytes to be set 
memset(arr, 0, (10*20*) * (sizeof *arr));
```

Comment: Here, finally - an answer using memset.  To use memset, find the starting address of the array (that's easy - it's the value of the array variable, or the address of the element with all indices = 0, if you prefer to be more explicit).  Then find the length of the array; this can be trickier.  Once both are known, call memset.

Comment: ajay, more like "If the 2D array has automatic _or static_ storage duration, then you can use an array initializer list to set all members to zero."

Comment: `(a*b) * (sizeof *arr)` better as `sizeof *arr * a * b)` to prevent `a*b` overflow as `sizeof *arr * a` uses the wider of `size_t` and `a` math.

Answer (score 7):

If you have for example an array of integers and want to use memset explicitly:

```
int array[M][N];
```

You do not need to initialize at declaration with { 0 }.

just

```
memset(array,0,M*N*sizeof (int));
```

All of the above are correct because in order to get the right sizeof array, the array must have been initialized first.
And arrays decay to one level in pointers.

Comment: `memset(array,0,M*N*sizeof (int));` better as `memset(array,0,sizeof (int) * M * N);` to prevent math overflow of `M*N`.

Comment: ... even better as `memset(array, 0, sizeof array);`.

Comment: I am not so sure about your second comment @chux - Reinstate Monica. Need to look for more info on standardization versions to compare if there is a difference. Also on the first comment i think explicit declaration of datatype is read first either way. If overflow occurs due to multiply operation, i believe we will both have a problem either way. +from me though for thinking like this

Comment: `M*N*sizeof (int)` can overflow when `int array[M][N]` is OK with exceptional large `M, N`.  Consider `M, N` are both 0x10000, `int/unsigned` is 32-bit and `size_t` is 64-bit.  `M*N` overflows `int/unsigned` math --> UB.

Answer (score 3):

Below is an `important point` to understand when you want to use `memset()`:

`memset()` allows you to set the individual **bytes** of memory by the given value and **not** set the **whole** memory by the given value.

```
int arr[2][3] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }; //  1   2   3   4 ...  6

// Works as you expected
memset(arr,  0, sizeof arr);     //  0   0   0   0 ...  0
memset(arr, -1, sizeof arr);     // -1  -1  -1  -1 ... -1

// Looks strange !!! - Explanation below
memset(arr,  1, sizeof arr);     // 16843009 16843009 .... 16843009
```

`memset(arr, 1, sizeof arr);` internally reset all the individual **bytes** of the memory to **1**.

For example in 32-bit system:

```
00000001 00000001 00000001 00000001 = 0x01010101 = 16843009 != 1 (0x00000001)
```

Similarly

```
memset(arr, -1, sizeof arr);     // -1  -1  -1  -1 ... -1
```

internally reset all the individual **bytes** of the memory to **-1**(1111 1111).

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 = 0xFFFFFFFF = -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
int array[10][10]={0};
```

It will initialize all your array members to 0.

---

**C99 Standard 6.7.8.21:**

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

Comment: The Op specifically asked for memset.

Comment: @ash: I don't think OP understands the semantics of what S/he needs.In the very next sentence S/he quotes the functionality expected, which can simply be achieved using above there is no need for `memset`.And to be nit-picky the OP says "initialize", in strictly technical sense using `memset` does not "initialize" anything it just sets the memory to `0`.

Comment: I see your point. At the same time, memset can be used "to initialize" a space - i.e. set it's initial value.  Anyway, asking questions will clarify that.  Otherwise, the answer really needs to be for the question asked.  Keep in mind the Op may be using any one of a number of C compilers, of any age, on any platform...  I'm not arguing that this answer is bad in any way - just that it doesn't answer the question "as asked".

Comment: @ash: Appreciate the comments. The aim is to provide the best possible answer by trying to map it to *what OP needs* rather than *what OP asks.* Not necessarily all OP possess a clarity on the former, so I would leave OP to clarify on the need. And just to clarify, in any usage `memset` doesn't initialize anything.Initialization in technical terms means creating a object with specific values in a single step & `memset` can never do that.

Comment: If that's your goal, may I recommend asking questions before posting an answer?

Comment: @ash: It is a difference of perspective & after 2.5k+ answers & 3.5 yrs spent answering them, I think I will stick to my own judgement & perspective.Anyhow, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I see.  Just to let you know - if I were searching for exactly what the Op asked, i.e. how to use memset on a multi-dimensional array, and found your answer, no amount of reputation or years would help.  I'm sorry you feel that reputation and time entered overrides all other judgement or valid input.

Comment: @ash: As I said it is a matter of perspective & I will leave it at that. I did not discard your perspective so just harping about it is no value add. I tried explaining my perspective but you seem to have no regard for any other rather than your own, which is a pity. It is really sad & pitiful that recording a downvote seems to be a part of your feeling sorry process.May you get more wiser & tolerant with time & experience.

Comment: I downvoted for the reasons stated: you didn't answer the Op's question, and if I were looking to answer the same question, I would be frustrated to find this answer.  If the Op changes the question, I'll reconsider.  Please answer his question, as asked.  I'm giving very valid, actionable feedback.  "I have a lot of experience and points, and therefore, I'm right," is not valid and not actionable.  I"m sorry if you feel it's a personal attack - it is not.  And thank you for your efforts in general.  Sincerely.

Comment: @ash: The answer will stay as it is for it is the most technically correct answer to the Q being asked, reasons for the same are already stated in the comments.So yes I am right because of that.As for the exp & rep, as I stated yes I will use them as a guiding principle in building my own perspective. As for the rest of the blabber I will refrain to comment any further.

Comment: @AlokSave as ash told you, I arrived on your answer because I would like to memset a two dimensional array, not initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Alok Save's answer is the best one, as it works for any type of array. You can also reset the array later , e.g.:

```
{
    T const blank[10][10] = { 0 };
    STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof blank == sizeof array);
    memcpy(&array, &blank, sizeof array);
}
```

This works for all types.

If you really want to use `memset` then you can do:

```
memset(&array, 0, sizeof array);
```

If you only have a pointer to the first element of the array, then:

```
memset(ptr, 0, number_of_elements * sizeof *ptr);
```

However, these versions set all-bytes-zero, which might not be a valid representation for floating-point types and pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

*Initialization*, in C, is a specific thing.

*Initialization* occurs at definition time and not later.

```
int a[M][N] = { 0 };  // Initialization

int b[M][N];
memset(b, 0, sizeof b);  // Assignment
```

---

OP comments:

> This is my initialization code of define two dimensional array and i have to create two dimensional dynamic array, for this reason, i declare it in this way. `int **matrix; int` **back;

In this case `matrix` is *not* a 2D array.  It is a pointer to a pointer.

Pointers are not arrays.  Arrays are not pointers.

To allocate an array of pointers to zero'd `int` data:

```
int **matrix = malloc(sizeof matrix[0] * M);
if (matrix) {
  for (size_t m = 0; m < M; M++) {
    matrix[m] = calloc(N, sizeof matrix[m][0]);
  }
}
```

If obliged to use `memset()`:

```
    // matrix[m] = calloc(N, sizeof matrix[m][0]);
    matrix[m] = malloc(sizeof matrix[m][0] * N);
    memset(matrix[m], 0, sizeof matrix[m][0] * N);
```